# How to change circle at end of moderation lines in plotmod()?

Tags: r, plot, regression, interaction

I am trying to plot a moderation effect using the plotmod() function in R. Because I need it for a journal, it has to be black-and-white. This means that the two lines representing effects of the moderator when high or low values should be different from one another - i.e. one ending with circles, the other with crosses; or one with a full line and the other with a dashed line.

I have not been successful at adapting the moderation plot, neither have I been able to find any topic that would help me with the answer. Thank you for any help.

Here is my code:

```
    model_lm6<-lm(ZEA4items~ZESEsum*ZEC3dim, data = df)

    moderation_plot<- plotmod(model_lm6, x = "ZEC3dim", w = "ZESEsum", 
                          x_label = "EC", w_label = "ESE", 
                          y_label = "EA", 
                          w_method = "percentile", graph_type = "tumble")
    
    moderation_plot + theme(plot.caption = element_blank()) + 
      scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black")) + 
      theme_bw()
```

Here is my moderation plot as I have been able to do it.

[Moderation plot with circles at ends of both lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf6hU.png)